# How do I vertically stack 4 text boxes?

Tags: html, css, stack, alignment

I have made my Google Advanced Search Page and it functions the way that I want it to. The problem is I can't seem to write the correct CSS to make the text boxes to stack vertically to the right of the text. I want all 4 of the 'blank' text boxes to be aligned to the right, I can moved all 4 boxes, but they still won't align. Any suggestions? I feel that it is probably some problem with my CSS.

```css
.advanced h1 {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: maroon;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.advanced img {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}

.finder {
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

hr {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.field {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

.field input {
    display: flex;
}

.advancedbtn input {
    margin-left: 700px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Advanced Search</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-right"><a href="./index.html">Search</a><a href="./images.html">Images</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="advanced"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="google image">
        <h1>Advanced Search</h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="finder">
        <h2>Find Pages With...</h2>
    </div>
    <form action="https://google.com/search" name="f">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="field1">all these words:</label><input type="text" class="textinput" id="field1" value="" name="as_q">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="field2">this exact word or phrase: </label><input type="text" class="textinput" id="field2" value="" name="as_epq">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="field3">any of this words: </label><input type="text" class="textinput" id="field3" value="" name="as_oq">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="field4">none of these words: </label><input type="text" class="textinput" id="field4" value="" name="as_eq">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="field5">numbers ranging from: </label>
            <input type="text" class="textinput1" id="field5" value="" name="as_nlo"><span class="seperator">to</span>
            <input type="text" class="textinput2" id="field5" value="" name="as_nhi">
        </div>
        <div class="advancedbtn"><input type="submit" value="Advanced Search"></div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using the flex container might be of some help here. I created the flex class and added it to your form. I then created a #form id and set the flex-direction to column so the items travel vertically instead of horizontally, and then set align-items to the flex-end (or to the right). If you want the text input to be more narrow just mess with the width property in the #form on the style editor. Hope this helps!

```
 <form action="https://google.com/search" name="f" id="form" class="flex">
```

Above is all I changed in the HTML. Below is what I added to the top of the CSS.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
#form {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90vw;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```